# Isomorphic Submodules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I would like to solve the following question: Let $M=\oplus_{i\in I}M_i$ be a direct sum of right $R$-modules and $X$ a nonzero submodule of $M$. Then there exists some $i\in I$ auch that $X$ and $M_i$ have nonzero isomorphic submodules.

I was telled to consider this:
Let $a\in X\setminus\{0\}$. Then $a=a_{i_1}+...+a_{i_n}$ with $a_{i_k}\in M_{i_k}\setminus\{0\}$ unique. I got a hint to consider an $a$ with "minimal support", so where the $n$ is minimal (but not $0$). But how I can use that?

Comment: Uhm... What does it mean for $X$ and $M_i$ to "have non-zero isomorphic submodules"? The obvious intepretation seems false: for instance, say, $R=\Bbb R$, $M=\Bbb R[x]=\bigoplus_{n\in\Bbb N} \Bbb Rx^n$ and $X=\Bbb R1\oplus \Bbb Rx\oplus\Bbb Rx^2$. Then, $X$ has submodules of dimension $2$, but none of the $\Bbb Rx^n$ has.

Comment: I understand it like this: They have one isomorphic submodule, not that all have to be isomorphic.

Comment: Your idea doesn't work, because you can't assume $a_i\in X$.

Comment: Thanks, I got my mistake. Any idea how to solve the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take some $a \in  \bigoplus M_i$ with minimal support, say $a = a_1 + \ldots + a_n$. Now, consider cyclic modules $< a>_R \leq X$ and $<a_1>_R \leq M_1$; let's see they're isomorphic via the projection homomorphism $\pi(a_1 + \ldots +a_n):=a_1$:

$\pi$ is obviously onto and if $\pi(ar) = 0$, the first coordinate of $ar$ is zero contradicting the minimality of the support of $a$.